# System apps location on Android Jelly Bean

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, 4.2-jelly-bean, 4.3-jelly-bean, system-apps

I chose to pose this question here, since I don't have any Jelly Bean device nearby.

On Android **KitKat**, system apps are located at **/system/priv-app/**. On **Lollipop** and **Marshmallow**, instead, they're placed under **/system/priv-app/name-of-the-app/**.

Following a similar fashion, I would like to know the path of those apps which are installed as **system apps**, on Android devices in a version range going from **4.1.x** to **4.3.x** (namely, all of the Jelly Bean builds).

Are their APKs located under the **/system/app/** folder directly, are they placed in a folder of the same name of the corresponding app, or are they present in a completely different folder?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried Android-x86? It can solve the query. BTW, in Android 5+, system apps are scattered in /system/app and /system/priv-app.

Comment: @Firelord Sadly, the quality of my Internet connection is not even good enough to allow me to download an ISO.

Comment: Have you read this: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/ccbf84f?

Comment: On my JDQ39 SDK 17 Jellybean 4.2.2 version all system files are in directly /system/app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, before Kitkat `.apk` files of system apps all went to `/system/app`. Kitkat added the `/system/priv-app` directory. The structure having an additional directory level came later (LP or MM).

References:

- [AOSP Privileged vs System app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19868138/2533433)
- [What's the difference of /system/app/ and /system/priv-app](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-platform/Vsa4IsJcOPE)
- [Android 5.0/Lollipop: Force rescan of /system/priv-app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26487750/2533433)